# angularjs transclude not working in my customized directive

Tags: angularjs

Can any one take a look at my simple directive and figure out why the transclude is not working?

html:

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <p>Your name</p><input ng-model="name"></input><button ng-click="greeting()">click</button>
    <greeter nationality="English" name="{{name}}">Hahahahah</greeter>
    <greeter nationality="French" name="{{name}}">Hahahahah</greeter>
    <greeter nationality="Russian" name="{{name}}">Hahahahah</greeter>
</div>    
</div>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);



app.controller("MainController", function($scope) {

});

app.directive("greeter", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "AE",
    scope: {
      name: "@",
      nationality: "@"
    },
    transclude: true,
    template: "<div style='display:block'>{{name}}<div ng-transclude></div></div>",
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      scope.$watch("name", function() {
        elem.html(greeting + " " + scope.name);
      });
      var greeting = "";
      if (scope.nationality === "English") {
        greeting = "Hello";
      }
      else if (scope.nationality === "French") {
        greeting = "Bonjour";
      }
      else {
        greeting = "Howdy";
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the transcluded content when you insert the greeting text with `elem.html(...)`.

Rather than manipulate the DOM with  jqLite, you can include the greeting text directly in your template.  For this to work, `greeting` must be a scope property (`scope.greeting` instead of `var greeting`).

```
template: "<div style='display:block'>{{greeting}} {{name}}<div ng-transclude></div></div>",
link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
  if (scope.nationality === "English") {
    scope.greeting = "Hello";
  } else if (scope.nationality === "French") {
    scope.greeting = "Bonjour";
  } else {
    scope.greeting = "Howdy";
  }
}
```

If you want to try the code for yourself, [here it is on Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GfpszFMBcNu1rFWYQPiF?p=preview).